# How to use fitcnb navie Bayes in matlab with discrete values?

Tags: matlab, classification, naivebayes

This is the data of malignant.

first column is for the gender and second is for the age and the third is for place of the melanoma and the fourth is for the diagnosis
[this the image of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPOsr.png)

```
%male = 1; female = 2
% head/neck = 1   upper extremity = 2   lower extremity = 3    torso = 4
% unknown = 1   nevus = 2    melanoma = 3


d = [1 45 1 1;
     2 45 2 1;
     2 50 3 2;
     2 55 2 3;
     2 50 2 3;
     1 55 4 3];
c = {'benign';
    'benign';
    'benign';
    'malignant';
    'malignant';
    'malignant';};
```

`Mdl = fitcnb(d,c,'CategoricalPredictors',[1 2])`

this is the output

```
A normal distribution cannot be fit for the combination of class malignant and predictor x4. The data has zero variance.
```

Comment: So this is a bit of a long shot because I haven't checked the math in a while but I think you get this error because you always have the same value for the 4th feature of your malignant tumors. Which means they have null variance and probably break naive bayes

Comment: Also there are a few philosophical points here, assuming this is not just a toy example. First you need much more data to do machine learning. Second, naive Bayes' assumption that each feature makes an equal contribution to the prediction is obviously wrong since, from your data, it seems I can predict the output based only on the diagnosis (4th feature). Whether or not this is a toy example, I suggest you put more data in it and make it a bit richer.

Comment: thank you sir for your comment, I have a very big data but written in numbers and string like the age is in format integer and the gender is written in string, so I took some of the data and change it manually, do you think that I should write a script to change to the format that bayes could understand it

Comment: And how can I change the equal contribution

Comment: I think you might have enough feature, if you more subjects you might be alright.

Answer (score 0):

You had to make the response vector a categorical vector and create some variance in the data:

```matlab
clear;
d = [1 45 1 1;
     2 45 2 1;
     2 50 3 2;
     2 55 2 3;
     2 50 2 3;
     1 55 4 4]; % Change 3 -> 4 to create variance
c = {'benign';
    'benign';
    'benign';
    'malignant';
    'malignant';
    'malignant'};

X = d;
Y = [0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1];
Y = categorical(Y, [0; 1], {'benign', 'malignant'});

Mdl = fitcnb(X, Y, 'CategoricalPredictors', [1, 2])
```